# Can't run c/c++ codes in code::blocks 13.12 on linuxmint 17: Status 255

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks, linux-mint

I am not able to run any C/C++ programs in code::blocks. Could anyone please suggest why this is happening? Currently I have the gnu c and g++ compilers installed on the system.
The error message on building and running this simple c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("55");
    return 0;
}
```

is:

> Checking for existence: /home/user1/Desktop/progs/a Executing: xterm -T '/home/user1/Desktop/progs/a' -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner "/home/user1/Desktop/progs/a" (in /home/user1/Desktop/progs)
>
> Process terminated with status 255 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))

Comment: Please, format the error message as code.

Comment: Does /usr/bin/cb_console_runner exist?

Comment: yes it does exist . @mafso

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two options:

- Install `xterm`

or

- In CodeBlocks, go to `Settings->Environment`, go to `Terminal to launch console programs`, and select an appropriate terminal.

What's currently happening is that CodeBlocks is attempting to run your program with `xterm`, which isn't installed on your machine.

Comment: exactly what was happening. thanks ! changed terminal to the installed one and it works. though why code blocks had set up "xterm" as default terminal when it wasn't even installed here, i won't know

Comment: Based on this answer (Thank you): In linux Mint/Ubuntu:  1.install xterm-> sudo apt-get install xterm
2. Then in codeblocks  go to settings->Environment..->Terminal to launch console programs: xterm -T $TITLE -e

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Mint with MATE Desktop do as descriped above:

In CodeBlocks,

- go to Settings->Environment,
- go to "Terminal to launch console programs",
- select GNOME terminal.
- EDIT/exchange manual "gnome-terminal" to "mate-terminal".
  Click ok to confirm and "run" in CodeBlocks should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue once, maybe your program hasn't be properly ended the last time you ran it, so it is still open hence the issue while running it again