# A program in C language made by CodeBlocks IDE runs with a double-click in Windows but not in Ubuntu. why?

Tags: c, linux, windows, user-interface, ubuntu

I am learning C. I am using Ubuntu as main OS but I also have Windows 7 for testing in another partition. I have made a program in C in both OSes using Code Blocks. When I double click the compiled file of program in windows it runs, but when I do the same in Ubuntu it does not run. I have also created `.desktop` file for it, but even then it doesn't run. But using the command.someone told me code GUI in.so how can i code GUI in it? also why it runs on windows?

```
./addition
```

makes it run in terminal. But I want to run it using GUI. I am clicking on its icon but its not opening.Do i need to code GUI for it?

[image]

source code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,s,d;


printf("type the values u want to add and give tab between them\n");


scanf("%d %d",&a,&s);

d=a+s;

printf("addition is %d",d);


system("read -p 'Press Enter to EXIT...' var");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because when you run the application through the GUI on a Linux system it doesn't have a terminal connected to it, and so have nothing to read from or write to. Different operating systems behave differently.

Comment: In Windows, apps built for console will open a console window when they run (and close it when they are finished, if they are started from, say, the Explorer). This is not the case in other OSes.

Comment: Do you select the Gnome therminal in settings -> Environment?[How to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560654/cant-run-c-c-codes-in-codeblocks-13-12-on-linuxmint-17-status-255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in linux if you run a shell program from the desktop, it does not have a std input or output attached. For this reason you cannot see anything about it.

A quick solution would be to open a terminal and run it from there.

Two easy options if you don't know how to run the program from terminal:

A) Drag the icon of the program into the terminal, it will automatically build the full path to run it

B) Move to the program's home folder and run it from there "./programName"

I hope this helps mate.

Comment: so you mean that i cant open it by double clicking on its icon? or code GUI in it?aslo can i create GUI for command "./program name" ?

Comment: Sure you can create a GUI, but as far as I can see from your code snippet, you are writing a traditional Terminal/Shell application. Best way would be to run it from there. Besides, you will be able to catch the standard errors generated from your application which is very important in the development phases of these applications.

Comment: Dear Friend, we risk to go a bit off topic I believe.

I usually develop my solutions requiring a GUI on different platforms with GTK+ https://www.gtk.org/

Comment: what is GTK. my dad was talking abut that. but he says that its too deep for you to learn.